# the killed man or the murdered man

Tags: phrases

When you refer to "a man killed in a murder case", I understand you'll say "the murdered man" instead of "the killed man."
Why isn't the expression "the killed man" used?

Comment: This is a grey area. With other nouns ('Ukrainian sources often refer to the killed protesters as the Heavenly Hundred.' / '... as tributes are paid to the killed MP ...') the attributive usage doesn't sound as unnatural, and there are certainly plenty of examples of its use on the internet. But with -ing and -ed forms, individual cases need checking for idiomaticity (the man wanted by the police, the man wanted, the wanted man // a talented boy, a girl talented in poetry // a boy raised in an orphanage ...) and differences in meaning (an annoying child vs a child annoying the neighbours ...).

Comment: For one thing, "killed man" is not particularly idiomatic.  There would be a preference for something like "the man who was killed" instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fact already mentioned that "killed" is less specific than murdered, I'd say that "the killed man" is unidiomatic.

"Killed" and "murdered" are both verbs, but here they are used as an adjective, making them [attributive verbs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb).

By using these verbs without an object as in your examples, they become deverbal adjectives (verbs behaving solely as an adjective). Other examples of deverbal adjectives (from that wiki page)

> It was a very **exciting** game.
> **Interested** parties should apply to the office.

A verb used as an adjective that is **not** deverbal has the verb after the noun and often, but not always, has a verb phrase. See the following examples (verb in bold, verb phrase is italics):

> The man ***killed** by the bus* was  a hard worker.
>
> The people ***interested** in applying* were all in line.
>
> The man **killed** was tall.

I'm not clear on what the rules are for when verbs can be used as deverbal adjectives, rather than just adjectival phrases. As a native American English speaker, " the killed man" (deverbal) sounds incorrect but "the man killed" (adjectival, but not deverbal) sounds fine.

Comment: A good link. However, a deverbal usage is one that uses what was once a verb(-form) as a true adjective, noun etc. Thus _Three large **paintings** were stolen_, where 'painting/s' is a noun (albeit having doubtless arisen from the older and still common participle, via the verb-noun 'gerund' form). In 'The batsmen dismissed could not handle the spin of Warne', 'dismissed' is not deverbal.

Comment: Right: that is why I said that my second set of examples are NOT deverbal. I made some minor edits that might clarify.

Comment: I'm saying that the 'without an object / by-phrase' test isn't definitive. In ''The batsmen dismissed could not handle the spin of Warne', the word 'dismissed' retains some 'verbiness'.

Comment: Could you explain why? I was unable to find much more information on deverbal nouns, but what I have matches up with the information I did find. I think deverbal before the noun versus verbal after might need what you're getting at, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There are elements remaining from the original relative clause. 'The batsmen who were dismissed could not handle the spin of Warne' ==> 'The batsmen dismissed could not handle the spin of Warne'. Few true adjectives would be used post-nominally: 'The competent batsmen _could_ handle the spin of Warne.' Essentially, a true adjective refers solely to the referent of the noun, whereas a 'verbal adjective' (using the term in a way analagous to that in which 'verbal noun' has been used by some grammarians)  tells both of the state of the referent of the noun and the event etc leading to that state.

Comment: I think I've incorporated your comment into my answer. Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 0):

The term usually used off-late is "**the murder victim**".

Check the google [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20murdered%20man%2Cthe%20killed%20man%2Cthe%20murder%20victim&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20murdered%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20killed%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20murder%20victim%3B%2Cc0) below, including terms suggested by you. You are still right in absolute terms but the trend is changing.

[image]

Edit: Arctic Tony is right too. *Killed* does not always mean *murdered*. There are other ways to get killed.